# Почему сервис не может получить зависимости глобального модуля?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Так как глобально зарегистрированный `Guard` требует внутри себя `Reflector`, `JwtService` и `ConfigService`, было принято решение сделать глобальный модуль, который импортирует в себя вышеуказанные зависимости.

```
@Global()
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            ...
        }),
        JwtModule.registerAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory(configService: ConfigService): JwtModuleOptions {
                return {
                    signOptions: {
                        algorithm: 'HS256',
                        issuer: configService.get('JWT_ISSUER'),
                    },
                };
            },
        }),
        Reflector,
    ],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

А затем он импортируется в AppModule:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        CommonModule /* <-- */ ,
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: AuthGuard }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Помимо `Guard`, я использую `JwtService` в `JwtFactoryService`, который используется для генерации токенов при аутентификации. Так как `JwtModule` уже зарегистрирован глобально, я не импортирую его в AuthModule, но, почему-то зависимости из `CommonModule` не переходят к `AuthModule`.

```
Potential solutions:
- If JwtService is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtFactoryService (?, ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил все сервисы импортируемых в `CommonModule` модулей в секцию providers, а затем и в exports. Не знаю, костыль это или нет, но оно работает.

```
@Global()
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({}),
        JwtModule.registerAsync({})
        Reflector,
    ],
    providers: [ConfigService, JwtService, Reflector],
    exports: [ConfigService, JwtService, Reflector],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```